Are questions about names on topic?
Occasionally questions about how to name pets appear. For a recent example see this one. My first instinct is to vote to close them (they seem to be the textbook example of opinion-based). What does the community think?

I perfectly agree: questions like this one are both half off-topic (proper names are part of a language, but borderline ones, often taken from other languages etc.) and 100% opinion-based.

In my opinion, the problem with this kind of question is that it's highly opinion-based.

Essentially, the question is saying Help with finding a name for my puppy, which is more of a request than a question. It doesn't ask for the meaning of a word, or the differences between two words in a specific context.
For example, a question asking using two different words as pet name could obtain answers explaining how one of the words is perceived from Italians, or which other meanings the word has that would suggest not to use it as pet name.
In general, I would rather avoid questions showing a picture and asking to find the name of what shown, if the OP doesn't give some more information, for example which words the OP should suit, or which words the OP found in a dictionary.
